# Generate many sample pairs from normal distribution

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, random

I trying to learn how to use R for statistics and I would like to how can I can I generate 20 000 (K number of pairs) times a set of two samples each with 50 points from the same normal distribution(mean 2.5 and variance 9)?

So far I know that this is how I make 50 points from a normal distribution:

```
rnorm(50,2.5,3)
```

But how do I generate 20 000 times a set of two samples so I can perform tests on the K pairs later?

Comment: If they're pairs what's the correlation among them? Or, perhaps you at least know the within effect and between group variances? Are negatives allowed? There's not enough information here to answer.

Comment: @John Negatives must be allowed if the samples are drawn from a normal distribution. Whether or not they are correlated is an important clarification, though, since nonzero correlation would invalidate my answer.

Comment: I know if they're genuine normally distributed negatives must be allowed but given the description as it is I don't necessarily trust true normal is what is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x   <-  lapply(c(1:20000), 
        function(x){
            lapply(c(1:2), function(y) rnorm(50,2.5,3))
})
```

This produces 20000 paired samples, where each sample is composed of 50 observations from a N(2.5,3^2) distribution. Note that `x` is a list where each slot is a list of two vector of length 50.

To t-test the samples, you'll need to extract the vectors and give them to function t-test.

```
t.tests <- lapply(x, function(y) t.test(x=y[[2]], y=y[[1]]))
```

Comment: These aren't *pairs* of vectors of length 50, just single vectors. Note that when this thread gets to SO, the MathJax won't work.

Comment: @gung Ah! I had trouble parsing the question's intent. I've updated it.

Comment: @user777
And what if I would to use for example a t test on each of the pairs? How the command look like? I tried this : ´y = lapply(x, t.test)´, but it will not work.

Comment: @user777

Thanks really a lot. And could you tell me how can I extract only the p-value and have a vector only with these values? I hope I do not ask to much, I am just a beginner.

Comment: Well, I could provide you the answer, but I think it would be most useful to you to learn about how R's data structures work. I'd start by using the str() command on the output to see how it's organized. Refer to any of the numerous free, introductory R manuals if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
 yourresults <- replicate(20000,{yourtest(matrix(rnorm(100,2.5,3),nc=2),<...>)})
```

or

```
 yourresults <- replicate(20000,{yourtest(rnorm(50,2.5,3),rnorm(50,2.5,3),<...>)})
```

where `yourtest` is whatever your function is that's carrying out some test, and `<...>` is whatever other arguments you pass to `yourtest`. The first one is suitable if it expects a matrix with two columns, the second is suitable if it expects two vectors. You can adapt this approach to other forms of input - such as a formula interface - in the obvious way.